# How to have one sticky element that does not overlap others when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-box library which in principle is adding this css

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

to my html
`<div class="sticky">..otherstuffhere</div><OtherComponent />`
This works fine in the sense that when I scroll down the component is always staying on the top.

My problem is that the component is going over other ocmponents overlapping, I want to keep it on top + same distance mantained always.[image]

In the image above the white is deleted for privacy reasons but basically is text and other components.
I want the finish cancel menu to be sticky but always before the other components.
There is also a header on top, so the order is

1. header
2. the sticky finish cancel menu that should show always when scrolling without showing on top of the part 3 other items)
3. list of items or whatever content

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to adjust the value of **z-index**.

Comment: z-index is already 10000 and component is shown fine over all others. My problem is something else that component overlaps. I tried padding-bottom margin-bottom but doesn't persist when scrolling

Comment: could you please share your code of this particular section?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).